# Weird eval result when using test

Tags: shell, testing, eval

Got a variable called `a`:

```
unset b
a="b"
```

Trying to take this statement:

```
if test -n "$(eval \$${a})"; then echo Y; fi
# Outputs nothing
```

which works nicely - it evaluates `\$${a}` to `$b`, which is empty and doesn't echo.

Trying to convert the above into something similar to this:

```
eval "if test -n \$${a}; then echo Y; fi"
# Outputs "Y"
```

which doesn't work - but even weirder:

```
eval "if test -z \$${a}; then echo Y; fi"
# Outputs "Y"
```

Why is this? How is the same statement outputting `Y` for both the above? Can I format the first statement as I've tried to using `eval` throughout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval "if test -n \$${a}; then echo Y; fi"
```

is the same as following where `a` is `b`:

```
eval 'if test -n $b; then echo Y; fi'
```

Since `b` is unset, and `$b` is **unquoted**, it is literally lost after expansion, thus `eval` evaluates the following:

```
if test -n; then echo Y; fi
```

For `-n` is not an empty string, `test -n` evaluates to true and `echo Y` is executed.

Comment: Oh my, the timing! I loaded the site to answer the question myself :) Thanks oguz!

Comment: And just to clarify, the spoonfed answer is `eval "if test -n \"\$${a}\"; then echo Y; fi"`